# Crystal Report with VB 2010 using multiple record selection formulas

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I have a Crystal Report where I am using the report viewer to list 3 dropdown boxes.  The user has the capability to select filtering from each of the boxes (for example, firstname and lastname dropdowns where they can choose "contains", begins with", etc.  Then another dropdown that contains "greater than", "less than", etc.  Each dropdown contains a textbox below them where the user can filter as they choose.

I've been able to get the firstname and lastname dropdowns to work in conjunction with each in the recordselectionformula.  However, when I try to add the formula for the sales I keep getting errors.  I've wracked my brain for hours and researched on how to add multiple formulas in the recordselectionformula, and I used that to add the firstname and lastname successfully, but every way to add the sales formula does not not work.  By itself (without the first and last name formulas) the sales formula works correctly, but I'm not able to get all 3 working together.

Any help is appreciated. Below is the code I have so far.

`Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    Dim reportToView As New CrystalReport1


    'User inputs filters for first name
    Dim firstname As String
    Dim searchFirst As String      
    firstname = txtFirstName.Text
    Dim firstnamesearch As String

    'Begins with
    If cboFirstName.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        searchFirst = firstname & "*"
        'Ends with
    ElseIf cboFirstName.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        searchFirst = "*" & firstname
        'Contains
    ElseIf cboFirstName.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        searchFirst = "*" & firstname & "*"
        'Equals
    ElseIf cboFirstName.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        searchFirst = firstname
    End If



    'User inputs filters for last name
    Dim lastname As String
    lastname = txtLastName.Text
    Dim searchLast As String
    Dim lastnamesearch As String

    'Begins with
    If cboLastName.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        searchLast = lastname & "*"
        'Ends with
    ElseIf cboLastName.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        searchLast = "*" & lastname
        'Contains
    ElseIf cboLastName.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        searchLast = "*" & lastname & "*"
        'Equals
    ElseIf cboLastName.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        searchLast = lastname
    End If


    'User inputs filters for sales data
    Dim lastsales As String
    lastsales = txtLastYearSales.Text
    Dim searchSales As String
    Dim salesearch As String

    'If "Greater Than" chosen
    If cboLastYearSales.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        searchSales = " >" + lastsales
        'If "Less Than" chosen
    ElseIf cboLastYearSales.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        searchSales = " < " + lastsales
        'If "Equal" chosen
    ElseIf cboLastYearSales.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        searchSales = " = " + lastsales
    End If

   'Dim firstnamesearch As String
    firstnamesearch = "{Person_Contact.FirstName} like """ & searchFirst & """"
    'Dim lastnamesearch As String
    lastnamesearch = "{Person_Contact.LastName} like """ & searchLast & """"
    'Dim salesearch As String
```

'(THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ADD TO THE RECORD SELECTION FORMULA BELOW)
        salesearch = "{Sales_SalesPerson.SalesLastYear} " + searchSales

```
    'AND formula (must select an option in all fields)
    reportToView.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula = "{Person_Contact.FirstName} like '" & searchFirst & "' AND {Person_Contact.LastName} like '" & searchLast & "'"
```

Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportToView

```
End Sub
```

`